# How can I emit signal form another class?

Tags: c++, qt

How can i emit signal from another class? In my implementation shown below I've got "unresolved external symbol error" when I try to emit signal in SerialPort::open method.
Code, head file of main window:

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    std::shared_ptr<SerialPort> serialPort;

private slots:
    void labelchange();
private:    
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

and the cpp file:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    serialPort(std::shared_ptr<SerialPort>(new SerialPort))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(serialPort.get(), SIGNAL(opened()),this,SLOT(labelchange()));
}
void MainWindow::labelchange()
{
    ui->testinLabel->setText("signal connected to slot");
}
```

and the other class method when i try emit signal:
head file:

```
class SerialPort : public QObject
{
public:
    SerialPort();
    void open()

signals:
    void serial_opened();
}
```

and cpp file:

```
void SerialPort::open()
{
    emit serial_opened();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just normal signal emitting from a class. Not "from another" class.

You are missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro, QObject do not really work with out it:

```
class SerialPort : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
    SerialPort();
    void open()

signals:
    void serial_opened();
}
```

And you need to have the file processed by `moc`. (happens automatically, if the files are listed in the .pro file)

Comment: When I add Q_OBJECT macro the error disappeared, but 3 other error arised, eg:LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall SerialPort::metaObject(void)const"

Comment: Then moc was not called. How do you compile it? qmake? Then check if all files are listed in the pro file and call qmake again

Answer (score 1):

SerialPort shall contain Q_OBJECT marco like this:

```
class SerialPort : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SerialPort();
    void open()

signals:
    void serial_opened();
}
```

Also please check your .pro file and check whether you added your SerialPort.h under HEADERS section.